# for loop for a curve vertex

Tags: javascript, p5.js

for the code below i am doing a random function for a curve vertex, my question is how can i make a couple curve-vertex's using a for-loop that with each refresh the location of the curve vertex changes.

```js
let x;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  x = random(80, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  noFill();
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(x, 91);
  curveVertex(x, 91);
  curveVertex(68, 19);

  curveVertex(32, x);
  curveVertex(32, x);
  endShape();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a for loop into the draw function and change the x value there:

let x;

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  // x = random(80, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  noFill();
  
  
  for(i = 0;i<=20;i++){
    x = random(80, 200);
    beginShape();
    curveVertex(x, 91);
    curveVertex(x, 91);
    curveVertex(68, 19);

    curveVertex(32, x);
    curveVertex(32, x);
    endShape();
  } 
  noLoop();
}
```

The above code loops 10 times, using a random x coordinate.

If you wish to 'clean the slate' after each change you can set noLoop and then use the keyPressed() event to redraw each time.

```
let x;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  // x = random(80, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  noFill();

    x = random(80, 200);
    beginShape();
    curveVertex(x, 91);
    curveVertex(x, 91);
    curveVertex(68, 19);

    curveVertex(32, x);
    curveVertex(32, x);
    endShape();

  noLoop();
}

function keyPressed() {
    redraw();
}
```